# Creating a elliptic or oval light source in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I want to create an oval light source for one application.
I have completely no idea about how to implement this, anyone has any ideas?

Can I just first create a spot light, then I rotate the projection matrix and then I can eventually get an oval spot light rather than a circle spot light.

Like, you use a plane to intercept a cone, you can get cone sections, from circle to elipse. If the plane you use that rotates a little bit instead of vertical to the light direction, you get a elipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start from a classic lightning shader:

```
// Eye vector (towards the camera)
vec3 E = normalize(EyeDirection_cameraspace);
// Direction in which the triangle reflects the light
vec3 R = reflect(-l,n);
// Cosine of the angle between the Eye vector and the Reflect vector,
// clamped to 0
//  - Looking into the reflection -> 1
//  - Looking elsewhere -> < 1
float cosAlpha = clamp( dot( E,R ), 0,1 );

color =
  // Ambient : simulates indirect lighting
  MaterialAmbientColor +
  // Diffuse : "color" of the object
  MaterialDiffuseColor * LightColor * LightPower * cosTheta / (distance*distance) ;
  // Specular : reflective highlight, like a mirror
  MaterialSpecularColor * LightColor * LightPower * pow(cosAlpha,5) / (distance*distance);
```

The circle shape of the light came from `float cosAlpha = clamp( dot( E,R ), 0,1 );`, more precisely from `dot(E,R)`. Because it's get the same value for a constant E;R angle (with a same origin point R can go in circle around E, the dot will remain unchanged).
To achieve an oval spot light you have to change the result of this dot product..

First you have to choose a main axis for the oval. Says M (perpendicular to E), and then transform R to increase it along M.

So perform `R = R + R*abs(dot(R,M))*factor;` before `dot(R,E)`.

*EDIT*

An implementation is available [here](https://shaderfrog.com/app/view/4061).